# How to get all user attributes from azure active directory using Microsoft Graph api

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph to get all azure active directory users but this api is not returning on-premises attributes , let me know how we can get all attributes(source anchor, onPremisesUserPrincipleName, onPremisesSamAccount, etc).

Comment: Please show your code, expected output and current output.

Answer (score 2):

Graph API by default only returns a limited set of properties( businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName).

To return an alternative property set, you must specify the desired set of user properties using the OData $select query parameter. For example, to return displayName, givenName, etc. (This is from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters).)

Also, When configuring Azure AD Connect there is a step that allows you to specify additional attributes that you wish to be replicated to Azure AD.